# Randomise participants into different groups

Tags: php, arrays, list, random, shuffle

**Problem:**

I have a text area in HTML that I wish to input a list of participants into. After submitting the form I would like PHP to take this list and randomise participants into groups of 4. If the participants are uneven (say 51), then the last group should be 3.

Further, I wish to request advice how the participants could be given a title in the output.

**Code:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $text  = trim($_POST['list']);
        $array = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
        shuffle($array);

        print_r($array);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Randomize groups</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="randomize.php" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Randomize groups</legend>
          <label for="list">Enter names of participants:</label>
          <textarea name="list" rows="12" cols="50" autofocus></textarea>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Desired output:**

**Group 1**

- Participant 5
- Participant 3
- Participant 7
- Participant 4

**Group 2**

- Participant 8
- Participant 2
- Participant 1
- Participant 6

Comment: "the last group should be 3" - that makes no sense. Be precise.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath If you have 51 participants and divide them into groups of 4, how many people will there be in the last group?

Comment: And if it's not 51, say 49?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Again, if you have 49 people  and divide them into groups of 4, how many people will be in the last one?

Comment: It's a thrill having a conversation with you.

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest doing it so:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $text  = trim($_POST['list']);
    $array = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
    $half = count($array)/2;
    shuffle($array);
    $groups = array_chunk($array, $half);
    foreach($groups as $key=>$value){
        $key++;
        echo "<h2>Group $key</h2>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($value as $participant){
            echo "<li>$participant</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: It's not `$half`, it's `4`.